# Winforms DataGridView with DataGridViewButtonColumn(Button) and multiselect mode enabled losing information on clicking grid row Button

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, multi-select

I have DataGridView with multi-select mode on and Grid row having DataGridViewButtonColumn(Button).I can select mutiliple rows using CRTL and SHIFT keys same as windows folder/file functionality but when I click on row button(DataGridViewButtonColumn) on any row after doing multi-selection this multi selected row information is getting lost and the current row is highlighted.I required to preserve this multi selected row information.If I use CTRL key while clicking on row button the current is deselected/selected.

I am using VS 2012, c# and winforms. What is the best way to hold multi selected row information on datagridview having buttons and checkbox on each grid row? Thanks for any help in advance and any suggestions/code snippets appreciated.

DatagridView properties Set:

```
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        dataGridView1.MultiSelect = true;
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to customize your own `DataGridView`. This allows you to add custom code to the `WndProc` then you can catch the message `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, check if the mouse is down on a `DataGridViewButtonCell` to discard that message. Somehow the `CellContentClick` is still raised (this is done by the internal implementation of `DataGridView`). However after discarding the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, the `Button` looses the look and feel of *pressed state*. That's a little annoying. So to mimic that state, we have to draw the button ourselves. Drawing the button makes us mimic more states than just the *pressed state* (such as *hot state*, *normal state*). Here is the code for you, works perfectly:

```
public class CustomGrid : DataGridView
{
    DataGridViewCell downButton;
    DataGridViewCell lastHoveredCell;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x201)//WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201
        {
            HitTestInfo ht = TryHitTest(m);
            if (ht.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
            {
                downButton = this[ht.ColumnIndex, ht.RowIndex];
                if (SelectedCells.Count > 1&&downButton is DataGridViewButtonCell){                                    
                   InvalidateCell(ht.ColumnIndex, ht.RowIndex);
                   return;
                }
            }
         } else if (m.Msg == 0x202) downButton = null; //WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202
         else if (m.Msg == 0x200) { //WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x200
            HitTestInfo ht = TryHitTest(m);
            if (ht.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
            {
                if (lastHoveredCell != this[ht.ColumnIndex, ht.RowIndex]){
                    if(lastHoveredCell != null &&
                       lastHoveredCell.DataGridView!=null)        
                       InvalidateCell(lastHoveredCell);                        
                    lastHoveredCell = this[ht.ColumnIndex, ht.RowIndex];
                    InvalidateCell(lastHoveredCell);                        
                }
            }
         }            
         base.WndProc(ref m);            
    }
    private HitTestInfo TryHitTest(Message m)
    {
        int x = m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff;
        int y = m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16;
        return HitTest(x, y);
    }
    protected override void OnCellPainting(DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex > -1 && e.RowIndex > -1 && this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewButtonCell)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);
            Rectangle buttonBounds = e.CellBounds;
            string text = ((DataGridViewButtonColumn)Columns[e.ColumnIndex]).Text;
            var buttonState = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.PushButtonState.Normal;
            if(buttonBounds.Contains(PointToClient(MousePosition))){
                buttonState = MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left && downButton == this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] ?
                              System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.PushButtonState.Pressed :
                              System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.PushButtonState.Hot;
            }                                
            ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(e.Graphics, buttonBounds, text, e.CellStyle.Font, false, buttonState);                
        }
        else base.OnCellPainting(e);            
    }
    protected override void OnColumnWidthChanged(DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e) {
        base.OnColumnWidthChanged(e);            
        InvalidateColumn(e.Column.Index);
    }  
}
```

This screen shot shows that one button is being pressed while all the selected cells are still being selected.

[image]

Comment: I have implemented CellContentClick  event through which I am doing action of button click event.

Comment: @user421719 See updated code (just around the line you pointed out). Looks like you have some code removing some row. I'm pretty sure the updated code would work.

Comment: Checkbox on grid row had some issues for selection on check/uncheck event  
Changed following code of method - protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) ------------------> if (SelectedCells.Count > 1 && (downButton is DataGridViewButtonCell || downButton is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell) )

Comment: Hi King I am facing issue when I click multiple the same button on grid row sometimes it does not respond.When I select another row using row header than it starts responding, could you help me in solving this issue?

Comment: @user421719 it's not clear what your problem is now. Please describe it step by step so that I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Double click was not handled in above code,only single click handled  WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201.When user clicks button twice or more quickly it is raised as double click event that I fixed now... thanks happy coding....